# Internal Server Error on Twilio Component to Send Bulk SMS to Campaign Members

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, appexchange, twilio, sales

We have installed Twilio App for Salesforce and configured it. The 1 to 1 Contact message is working fine, while Bulk SMS to Campaign Member is showing Internal Server error as below:

Error ID: 1754947416-96315 (119852647)

Checked debuglog too but didn't find anything.[image: l]

Comment: Didn't mean to save the duplicate, but essentially, the answer to this post boils down to - you have to contact Salesforce Support. You have run into a gack and no one on this site will be able to help you here.

Comment: Ok, Actaully I reached to Twilio support which package application we are using. And they recommended me to post a question here to get a solution faster.

Comment: Given that the error is a gack, that advice was not very well grounded. Much better to reach out to Salesforce directly.